# prestashop ajax controller call

Tags: php, jquery, prestashop

I am trying to call controller in module using Ajax in prestashop 1.5, and I'm having hard time doing this.

I've created controller in module under the path:

```
$refresh_url = ($this->_path)."front/blockdiscoversellers.php";
```

and made instructions for button in js like:

```
var refresh = {
    call: function() {
        var $refresh = $("#manufacturer-refresh");

        $refresh.click(function(e) {
            refresh.ajax();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    },
    ajax: function() {
        var url = $("#manufacturer-refresh").data("url");

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'get',
            data: {
                controller : 'BlockDiscoverSellers',
                ajax : true
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

and the body of controller looks like :

```
class BlockDiscoverSellers {

    public function __construct()
    {
        die(var_dump($this->refreshManufacturers()));
    }

    public function refreshManufacturers()
    {
        $result = array("test" => "TESTER");

        return Tools::jsonEncode($result);
    }
}
```

I'm getting success in Ajax call but it looks like class and constructor are not initiated, so I am quite stuck with this problem.

Comment: so you understand that you are calling a script which does not instantiate your class **and** that the problem is probably that your class is not instantiated.... what about instantiating your class??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that prestashop when you use ajax call uses only structural type of programming. That means in ajax call there can be no class of any sort bootstrap will never initiate it even with controller parameter, and you have to die at the end of file ...